# Two components with the same id '**{BehaviorID}**' can't be added to the application

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, ajaxcontroltoolkit, cascadingdropdown

I am trying to implement **CascadingDropdown** in **AJAXToolKit** on a **GridView**. 
Everything works fine and the dropdown fetch and populate data.

But, when I try to add **BehaviorID** attribute to the dropdown (to help identify it in JavaScript so that I can bind an `add_populated()` function to it, it gives me the following error message.

> "Two components with the same id '**{BehaviorID}**' can't be added to the application."

I doubt that it is because the application is trying to assign the same BehaviorID to each cascading drop down in the GridVivew.

Any ideas?

**ASPX :**

```
<asp:GridView ID="grdTInfo" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False"   onrowdatabound="grdTInfo_RowDataBound" ShowFooter="True"  EnableModelValidation="True"  >
<Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TDBID" Visible="False">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox8" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TSId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:Label ID="TSID" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TSId") %>'></asp:Label>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:BoundField HeaderText="SL.No" >
    <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" 
        Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="1%" 
        Wrap="False" />
    </asp:BoundField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HPname">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("PName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" 
        Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="15%" 
        Wrap="False" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlPractice" runat="server" Width="100%">
            </asp:DropDownList>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="HTName">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox3" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" 
        Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="15%" 
        Wrap="False" />
        <ItemTemplate>
            <cc1:DynamicDropDownList ID="ddlTask" runat="server" Width="100%"  
                OnSelectedIndexChanged="ddlTask_SelectedIndexChanged">
            </cc1:DynamicDropDownList>

            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown ID="ccdTask" runat="server" Category="Task" TargetControlID="ddlTask" PromptText="Select Task" LoadingText="Loading Tasks.." ServiceMethod="BindTaskDetails" ServicePath="CascadingDropdown.asmx">
            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
    <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="STask">
        <EditItemTemplate>
            <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox4" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("STName") %>'></asp:TextBox>
        </EditItemTemplate>
        <ItemStyle BorderStyle="Solid" BorderWidth="1px" Font-Names="Calibri" 
        Font-Size="Small" HorizontalAlign="Center" VerticalAlign="Middle" Width="10%" 
        Wrap="False" />
        <ItemTemplate>

            <cc1:DynamicDropDownList ID="ddlST" runat="server" Width="100%" >
            </cc1:DynamicDropDownList>
            <ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown  BehaviorID="abc" ID="ccdST" runat="server" Category="ST" ParentControlID="ddlTask" TargetControlID="ddlST"  PromptText="Select Sub-task" LoadingText="Loading Sub-tasks.." ServiceMethod="BindSTDetails" ServicePath="CascadingDropdown.asmx" >
            </ajaxToolkit:CascadingDropDown >
        </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
</Columns>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some research, I found the solution.

While creating the **GridView**, we should have unique BehaviorID for each dropdown created in each row of **GridView**.

So, We can override the `grdTInfo_RowCreated` event to assign unique BehaviorIDs for each dropdown as below

```
 protected void grdvTimelogInfo_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            // Programmatically reference the PopupControlExtender
            CascadingDropDown cc1 = e.Row.FindControl("ccdTask") as CascadingDropDown;
            CascadingDropDown cc2 = e.Row.FindControl("ccdST") as CascadingDropDown;

            // Set the BehaviorID
            string behaviorID = string.Concat("cc1", e.Row.RowIndex);
            cc1.BehaviorID = behaviorID;

            string behaviorID2 = string.Concat("cc2", e.Row.RowIndex);
            cc2.BehaviorID = behaviorID2;
        }
    }
```